# DVBLink and DVBSky / Install a DVBs PCIE car on Ubuntu

Tags: pcie, dvb

I bought a DVBSky S952 V3 PCIe to run with DVBLink,

I keep having tunning failing for both 19.2 and 28.2.

Weirdly the name of the tuner are different “montage technology m88rs6000

I'm not sure is the driver is installed properly as when I enter :

`dmesg | grep -i dvb`

I have this result :

```
[    2.185166] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: card detected: DVBSky S952 V3
[    2.303310] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (SMI_DVB)
[    2.556122] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Montage Technology M88RS6000)...
[    2.562494] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVBSky S952 V3 port 0 MAC: 00:18:42:54:55:52
[    2.562509] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (SMI_DVB)
[    2.795378] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 1 frontend 0 (Montage Technology M88RS6000)...
[    2.801588] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVBSky S952 V3 port 1 MAC: 00:18:32:54:55:53
[    2.834750] Registered IR keymap rc-dvbsky
[    2.834778] rc rc0: IR (DVBSky S952 V3) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/rc/rc0
[    2.834806] input: IR (DVBSky S952 V3) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/rc/rc0/input16
[    3.983397] m88ds3103 6-0069: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw failed with error -2
[    3.983398] m88ds3103 6-0069: firmware file 'dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw' not found
[    4.088780] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVB: adapter 1 frontend 0 frequency 0 out of range (950000..2150000)
[    4.117392] m88ds3103 6-0069: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw failed with error -2
[    4.117393] m88ds3103 6-0069: firmware file 'dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw' not found
[    4.117593] m88ds3103 5-0069: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw failed with error -2
[    4.117594] m88ds3103 5-0069: firmware file 'dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw' not found
[    4.224187] SMI PCIe driver 0000:01:00.0: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 frequency 0 out of range (950000..2150000)
[    4.254776] m88ds3103 5-0069: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw failed with error -2
[    4.254777] m88ds3103 5-0069: firmware file 'dvb-demod-m88rs6000.fw' not found
```

Also do I need to provide any settings other than searching for 19.2 and 28.2 channels ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 DVBSky`? Thanks.

Comment: There's a description with a link to a firmware file in the [LinuxTV wiki entry on the DVBSky S952 v3](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVBSKY_S952_v3#Driver_and_firmware). I'll write a proper answer when this question is reopened. (Could someone please notify me about that?)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Reopened.